# In Split page template Load State is not working correctly?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am using split page template in my windows 8 application(C#) , according to its code  when we select any item from list view and then terminate app or press back button , it  should remember current selected item and after debugging it  I think its saving current selected value in pageState. But after reloading same page it fail to reload ( to select) same selected item. I tried with split app as well as adding split page to my application.
Is there any bug in split page template ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should set the SplitPage `NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"`.

And also make sure that every item has a unique id in

```
if (selectedItem != null) pageState["SelectedItem"] = selectedItem.UniqueId;
```

Answer (score 0):

The default Split Page template app is working appropriately for me.  If you select a group on the first page (ItemsPage) and then select an item from the list to get to the SplitPage, that item will persist through a suspension or a termination *while you are on the SplitPage*.

The application does not, however, remember that you've selected that item if you hit the back button. Once you return to the ItemsPage, even if you select the same group, it will load a 'new' version of the page and select the default first element. You'll have to add your own code if you want to restore the last selected item for each group.

Note there is also a property called [NavigationCacheMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode.aspx) which will allow the app to cache the ItemsPage; however, if you do that, you'll see the ItemsPage (and selected item) for the last group selected, even if you've selected a different group from the ItemsPage (in other words, that won't work here).

Lastly, be aware that to test the "Terminate" state, you'll need to run the app via the Simulator in Visual Studio and select Suspend and Shutdown. If you merely exit the app (Alt+F4 or swipe down), the app state is "ClosedByUser" and in that case the default would not be to restore state.